# Rails 5 API and devise flash undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to setup devise on this [new rails 5 API application](https://github.com/johndel/rails5-api-test). When I am trying to sign in (sending the correct email and password with a POST request to `/v1/sign_in`) I am getting the following error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<SessionsController:0x007fa0f14fd280>):

devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:157:in `set_flash_message'
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:164:in `set_flash_message!'
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:18:in `create'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
bullet (5.2.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
request_store (1.3.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I've tried some things to fix it, like adding the flash middleware here:
`https://github.com/johndel/rails5-api-test/blob/master/config/application.rb#L44`. I also tried to add it at the beginning with this code: `config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Flash)` but still no luck. Any idea why this doesn't work?

You can reproduce it if you setup the above application, seed it and try running this command: 
`curl -X POST -F "user[email]=istoselidas@gmail.com" -F "user[password]=example" localhost:3000/v1/sign_in`

**Update**
Seems that the `sign_in.json` is working out of the box, there is an issue however with the `password/edit.json` which seems to be a problem with devise (it approached it differently on this controller).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If you really want to keep Flash,

adding the middleware is indeed necessary. And you also need to include the Flash module in your `SessionsController`. The module `Flash` apparently has an implicit dependency on `Helpers`, so include that, too.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include ActionController::Helpers
  include ActionController::Flash
  ...
```

Note that Devise lets its controllers inherit from your `ApplicationController` and that one in turn inherits from `ActionController::API`, which is slimmer than the usual parent class `ActionController::Base`.

---

### However, you don't have to

Devise is actually aware of so-called navigational formats. Typically, this is only `:html` (which also happens to be the default format for requests if no other format is specified).

If you explicitly use the `:json` format with your request, devise will be smart and refrain from adding flashes.

For this to work, you will have to undo a configuration you made: You declared `:json` to be a navigational format. Don't. Revert that line in your devise initializer:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:json]  # THIS IS BAD
```

Then, use an extra `.json` suffix with your request and all will work as expected:

```
curl -X POST -F "user[email]=istoselidas@gmail.com" -F "user[password]=example" localhost:3000/v1/sign_in.json
```

You can get rid of the Flash middleware, too.

---

## Extended answer to extended question: password/edit.json

It seems that Devise's `PasswordsController` does *not* respect non-navigational formats when setting flash messages. Probably this was good enough so far because noone cared about `new` and `edit` actions with a JSON API. You in your specs are making sure these actions are not accessable, which is perfectly legitimate.

As far as I understand, this is a bug in Devise. Let's devise a pull request to fix it! :)

Your `PasswordsController` specializes `Devise::PasswordsController` by overwriting the `new` and `edit` actions. The reason why you still get the error is that the harmful code resides in a `before_filter` called `assert_reset_token_passed`.

Hence a quick and clean solution for you is to prepend your own filter.  You can use your `json_not_found` method. Since that method renders something, it will stop Devise's filter from being executed.
With this approach you also don't need to override the action methods any more.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  prepend_before_filter :json_not_found, only: [:new, :edit]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that in a new rails 5 API, when I do the above you suggested I am getting an error `ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat` so it is necessary to add `respond_to :json` on the application_controller (or individually on each devise_controller).

Comment: Seems like the error remains in other requests like `password/edit` here is an example https://github.com/johndel/rails5-api-test/tree/another_devise_attempt and https://github.com/johndel/rails5-api-test/blob/another_devise_attempt/spec/api/authentication_spec.rb#L38-L42

For testing it I tried `curl localhost:3000/v1/password/edit.json`

Comment: Please modify your question with the new intel, so other possible answers know what they are up against :) I'll add more debugging results to my answer. Thumbs up for filing an issue with the devise project!

Comment: Thank you for your awesome feedback! I managed to "silence" the `password/edit` as it is a get request and in an api it doesn't matter much (at least in the project I have in mind). Here is how https://github.com/johndel/rails5-api-test/blob/23702982e7037cf13ec0e7e084413186d5405ae1/app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb#L8-L11

I also added a spec regarding the change password functionality https://github.com/johndel/rails5-api-test/blob/23702982e7037cf13ec0e7e084413186d5405ae1/spec/api/authentication_spec.rb#L38-L57

Comment: Glad you liked it! \*happily grabs bounty\* :)

Comment: Hmm, overwriting `assert_reset_token_passed` seems odd, since it has a specific purpose and you are drastically changing that purpose. The name does not fit any more. If you don't like using `json_not_found` as a before_filter, then maybe you'd prefer to `skip_before_filter :assert_reset_token_passed, only: :edit`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly fix that works: override the create method of your SessionController, copy the code from the original method and remove the line that set the flash message:

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  # set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```